# How to use multiple RewriteRule rules in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using 2 RewriteRule rules in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#if it has member/photo/render_fast forward to photo_render.php
RewriteRule ^member/photo/render_fast(.*) /photo_render.php?r=$1 [L]
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

However this doesn't work, when I'm trying in my local machine, my Apache always use the second rule, and in my hosting server Apache always display an error.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your first rule says: if URL starts with `member/photo/render_fast` and requested resource is **NOT** a file **AND NOT** a folder, then forward it to `/photo_render.php`. Your 2nd rule says: redirect EVERYTHING to `/index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is the 2nd time around (after the URI has been rewritten to `/photo_render.php`) the 2nd rule is being applied, thus `/photo_render.php` is getting rewritten to `index.php`. You need to add a few conditions when you try to match something like `.` or `.*`. This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^member/photo/render_fast(.*) /photo_render.php?r=$1 [L]
# otherwise forward it to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note that this will also fail if for some reason you don't have photo_render.php.